# Markov Localization using control as an input

Tags: localization, odometry, probability

When using Hidden Markov Models in Global Localization problems on the prediction step there is a need to calculate the probability of robot's pose given the actions (control *u*, odometry):

```
p(Xt|Xt−1, Ut−1)
```

where xt-1 and ut-1 are the robot's previous pose and control.

There are different tutorials (this [one](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~allen/F15/NOTES/localization_1_to_4.pdf) for instance) and articles on the web with the examples, but most of these examples are for the 1D localization problem where action simply equals to 1 if the odometry is perfect.

What if I am considering 2D space?
For example in 1D example for time step T=1 I would compute like:

```
p(Xt = 2 | Xt-1 = 1, Ut = 1) = 1
```

How should I do the computations for 2D case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Multi-dimensional models

In the 2D case, $x_t$ is a vector with two components (e.g. position in $x$, $y$), but why stop at 2D? Often, the state vector $x_t$ will have your position in two or three dimensions, in addition to velocity and acceleration. Oftentimes we also include angular state in $x_t$ such as the heading and angular rate of change.

Your control is also often multi-dimensional, for example if you have a wheeled robot it could be the velocity of the left and right wheels.

### Linear case (Kalman filter!)

Typically we have a model that maps the previous state and control actions to a new state and control action. In the linear, time invariant case, we have matrices $A$ and $B$, and 
$$x_t = A x_{t-1} + B u_t $$
in this setting we would probably use a [Kalman filter](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~welch/kalman/) to keep track of our belief about the distribution of $x_t$.  The Kalman filter is nice because it gives a closed form solution to the estimation problem which is correct if noise/uncertainty is Gaussian.

### More general models

The markov approach (as I understand it) let's us move past these assumptions (linearity and Gaussian noise) by using approximation methods such as particle filters to estimate the belief distribution of our state $x_t$. The markov assumption is saying that we only need the distribution of $x_t$ (and don't need to use the distribution of $x_{t-1},x_{t-2},\dots$) when computing the distribution of $x_{t+1}$. I think the figure on slide 30 of the link you posted illustrates this quite well.

### Discrete (small) state space

As for your last question about how to find your belief: it depends on your application. If your state/controls are discrete, and you don't have very many of them, you can explicitly write down all of the transition probabilities $p(x_t \mid x_{t-1}, u_t)$ for every possible $x_t$, $x_{t-1}$ and $u_t$. Then when you do your estimation, you just look up the appropriate value.

### Further reading

Typically states are continuous, or there are too many to compute/store every possible transition.  If you're just getting started in this, try a Kalman filter and see how that works for you (there are many tutorials on them). If you want to see what else is out there, I recommend the [Probabilistic Robotics](http://www.probabilistic-robotics.org/) book, which gives a still quite good overview of different approaches (including Kalman filters) for this localization problem.